# How to programmatically assign user managed identity to Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Azure Data Factory in which I want to connect to Azure Synapse using User Assigned Managed Identity authentication type.

Three steps need to be done but unfortunately, I haven't noticed a possibility to programmatically set up step 1.

1. In Data Factory (Settings-> Managed Identities) assign User Managed Ideneitty
2. Create credentials
3. Create linked services

If I execute Azure ARM with only implemented second and third steps I got the following exception:
"The referenced user assigned managed identity in the credential is not associated with the factory".

Do you know how I can assign User-Managed Identity to Data Factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, documentation for Azure Data Factory ARM is limited. I found a solution based on the documentation of the Azure Storage ARM and below it's the solution:

```
 {
            "name": "[variables('dataFactoryName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('uamiName'))]": {}
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error messsage: "The referenced user assigned managed identity in the credential is not associated with the factory"

When doing CI/CD for arm-template I noticed that the auto generated arm-template from the datafactory only had identity type SystemAssigned. Even when when i have manually added a UserAssigned identity in the ADF GUI.

My Solution was to modify arm-template-parameters-definition.json with this.

```
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories": {
    "identity": "=:-identity"
}
```

Then in the parameter file you can pass in this :

```
    "dataFactory_identity": {
    "value": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "/subscriptions/<Insert_subscrptionId>/resourceGroups/<Insert_resourceGroupsName>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<Insert_userAssignedIdentitiesName>": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So in my case I didn't have to modify arm-teplate-paramters-definition.json file